# How to construct spiral phyllotactic pattern with the given number of spirals?

Tags: geometry, fibonacci-numbers, lucas-numbers

It is known that the spiral phyllotactic pattern is common in Nature, especially in Botany.

[image: The example of spiral phyllotactic arrangement of emerging flowers on Gerbera hybrida (doi: 10.1093/jxb/erw489).]

It consists of two group of clockwise and anticlockwise spirals, starting from the center. In most cases the number of those spirals are two consecutive Fibonacci numbers: $F_n, F_{n+1}$. Also there are patterns where number of spirals are doubled Fibonacci numbers, Lucas numbers, or Fibonacci ± 1.

The equations for generating some sort of a spiral phyllotaxis are:

$$
\phi = \pi(1+\sqrt{5}) \\
\forall n \in [0, N] \\
\theta = n \phi \\
r = \sqrt{n} \\
x = r \cos{\theta} \\
y = r \sin{\theta}
$$

How to change that equations to take into account the predefined number of spirals? For example, I want to generate a phyllotactic pattern consisted of (11, 18) spirals: 11 clockwise and 18 anticlockwise. How to do that?

UPDATE.

It looks that the number of visible spirals is depended on the radius of a pattern.